# How to create a 'Close Tab' button in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created an app using Google Sheets. I have created a hyperlink that opens a different Sheets file at the appropriate row to edit the relevant data, but now I want to create a clickable button that then closes that newly opened browser tab once the edit has been made, for it to return to the original sheet tab and continue with life.

Can someone provide me with easy to follow instructions on how to achieve this?  (I am aware of how to assign a script to a button, I just need help on the actual script required).

Comment: Hi there @DarrenFry! To help you developing a *close tab* action it would be very useful to know what you have already done. Could you please share the code for opening the tab?

Comment: Hi Jacques.  No code as such, just using a hyperlink in a cell that opens a new tab by default. 

However, if you have an idea on how else I could work it then I am open to ideas. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To close a generic page served from a web-app you can use the [`close()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close) method of the Client-side API from a button with a code similar to this one:

```html
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

Please, write back to me if this approach doesn't work in your scenario.

Comment: I have played around with this code, but I am a little unsure where it should be placed to be triggered?  I was having trouble making this into a function in Apps Script, which I then assume I assign as a script to a button?

Any chance you could give me a little more guidance on specifically how to make this work in Sheets?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there @DarrenFry! You should use that code in the `html` file as an [`<input />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) button. If you encounter problems with it, feel free to share the code so I can help you better.